# Additional help text to form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

When I create or edit `model CV`, I need to input some data in `birth_date` field. It's working, but I want to add some additional text to define some date format like `(yyyy-mm-dd)`. I'm using `cripsy` forms for better look of forms. How can I add this help text ?

my code:

template.html

```
{% block profile %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Edit your basic informations</h2>
    <hr>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class Cv(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=25, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    main_programming_language = models.CharField(max_length=15, null = True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)


@property
def age(self):
    return int((datetime.datetime.now().date() - self.birth_date).days / 365.25 )

def zapisz(self):
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.surname.encode('utf-8')
```

forms.py

```
class CvForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Cv
    fields = ('name', 'surname', 'city', 'birth_date', 'email', 'main_programming_language', 'specialization', 'interests', 'summary',)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def new_cv(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        cv = form.save(commit=False)
        cv.author = request.user
        cv.save()

        return redirect('proj.views.cv_detail', pk=cv.pk)
else:
    form = CvForm()
return render(request, 'new_cv.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can add `help_text` to your model fields:

```
birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="format (yyyy-mm-dd)")
```

see more Django [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#help-text) and [Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#help-text) docs.

You can also use external library [JQuery Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) too.